# Programatic focus event does not cause focus event handler to fire?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using a programatic focus event as follows:

```
resetInput: function (array, checkbox) {
    _.each(array, function (val) {
        $A.log('input cleared, focussed, blurred for ' + val.id)
        val.value = '';
        val.focus();
        val.blur();
    });
    if (checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = true;
    }
}
```

Then I capture it as follows:

```
applyEL: function (input_element, label_element) {
    var self = this,
        $input_element = $(input_element);
    $input_element.on("blur", function () {
        $A.log('Blur Event detected:');
        if (input_element.value === '') {
            $A.log(': with input blank');
            $A.toggleClass(input_element, 'toggle_border_show');
            $A.toggleClass(label_element, 'toggle_label_show');
            $A.animate(label_element, {property: 'fontSize', time: self.P.speed});
        }
    });
    $input_element.on("focus", function () {
        $A.log('Focus Event detected - ');
        if (input_element.value === '') {
            $A.log(' - with input blank:');
            $A.toggleClass(input_element, 'toggle_border_obscure');
            $A.toggleClass(label_element, 'toggle_label_obscure');
        }
    });
```

The focus and blur event listeners work fine when I fire them manually using the keyboard.

But the programatic versions do not work.

I noticed that my inputs where not resetting ( the event handlers did not fire properly ) and added in the log to determine this.

**Note:**

I also fired the focus and blur event handlers from the console and saw  no effect.

Comment: For more code see the site - http://www.arcmarks.com - you have to input something on the splash page and then flip the page back and forth using the menu up top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My man,

You will not be able to use focus and blur events on an element if its display is set to none.  ( it looks like a parent element is setting this ).

I would recommend you reset your inputs before you set the body element to hidden.

This should solve your problem.